# chai things - comprehensive list of should() methods

Tags: javascript, chai

I'm looking for a comprehensive list of methods you can call on a decorated object using the chai-things library for chai.js
so, for example :

myObject.should.METHOD_NAME.

What are all of the valid METHOD_NAMEs that can be called in the above statement. If valid method names are based on object type, is there a table listing methods per object type available ?

for example, here are some of the methods available:

- an
- change
- changes
- contain
- contains
- decrease
- decreases
- include
- includes
- increase
- increases
- length
- not
- be
- eql

Here is another example, if you call 'increase' on an array assertion you get an error, whereas if you call 'contain' it's okay.  I'm seeking the documentation that describes these rules. 
[image]

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the methods for `should` are available in the docs under "Expect / Should" (http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/), for example [here's the docs for `contain` (which is an alias of `.include`)](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#-include-value-):

> ## .include(value)
>
> @param{ Object | String | Number }obj
>
> @param{ String }message_optional_
>
> The include and contain assertions can be used as either property based language chains or as methods to assert the inclusion of an object in an array or a substring in a string. When used as language chains, they toggle the contains flag for the keys assertion.
>
> ```
> expect([1,2,3]).to.include(2);
> expect('foobar').to.contain('foo');
> expect({ foo: 'bar', hello: 'universe' }).to.include.keys('foo');
> ```

The docs show examples using the `expect(foo).to...` syntax, but `expect(foo).to.` and `foo.should` are completely interchangeable.

If you want you can also look at the source code - all of the core assertions are in one file; [chai/lib/core/assertions.js](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/lib/chai/core/assertions.js) - they're constructed using `addMethod` but each one comes with docs (the docs are used to generate the website) so it should be easy enough to read.

Every method is available from `.should` - but there are some special "properties" to help form approximations of english sentences, they don't do anything but they can be used to chain an assertion - these are

- to
- be
- been
- is
- that
- which
- and
- has
- have
- with
- at
- of
- same

(So if you really wanted to, you could write `'a'.should.to.be.been.is.that.which.and.has.have.with.at.of.same.equal('a')` - and this would have the same effect as `'a'.should.equal('a')`)

Comment: Ok, thanks.  So I suppose one could go through and write out a table of all the functions and which objects they can act upon.   For example,  you can use object.should.contain   where object is Array or String.   However if you call object.should.contain on anything else you'll get an error.  I really with they would list this out in their docs to be more clear.

Comment: @looshi you should file an issue over on the [chai issue tracker](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues) - we're always looking to improve documentation and any insight as to where it is lacking would be super valuable!

Comment: ok will do.  I haven't used chai for a few months, but when I start with it again maybe I will make the documentation table I have envisioned.  In fact, it could be autogenerated by running every chai function on each object type and printing the results, there are so many combinations this might be better and easier to maintain.   I don't think it's a real issue with the library, which is quite good btw, it's just a matter of formalizing the documentation, it seems like a few other people get confused as well e.g., https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/501.